# how can i format numbers in a php array?

Tags: php, formatting

Im putting values into an array.
example values:

```
14
15.1
14.12
```

I want them all to have 2 decimals.
meaning, i want the output of the array to be

```
14.00
15.10
14.12
```

How is this easiest achieved?
Is it possible to make the array automatically convert the numbers into 2 decimalplaces?
Or do I need to add the extra decimals at output-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try for example

```
$number =15.1; 
$formated = number_format($number,2);
```

now $formated will be 15.10

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.number-format.php) as a map function to [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-map.php)

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5.1);
$formatted_array = array_map(function($num){return number_format($num,2);}, $array);
```

Comment: @diEcho Because this method is efficient and a valuable skill to learn. The OP can apply this knowledge to future situations that may be more complicated than a simple number formatting.

Comment: array_map() isnt any more efficient, actually its more *inefficient* since its first copying the whole array, then looping through it. i would just loop through the array and be done with it. i wouldnt call array_map() a valuable skill either... just confuses newbies making them think thats the only and the only way to handle with arrays. it *can* be "useful" in some rare cases though... but i personally hate having too many helper functions that clutters the language into one-liner piece of... you know.

Comment: @Rookie: Unless you do a for($i), all array functions will "copy" the data, but note that copying in php memory is very simple, it's just references until there is a change, so an array_map that just reads data doesn't really affect performance or memory, but as soon as you change something in the "copy" it gets really copied.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin, i benchmarked again, for loop 6x faster. you can try it yourself. just remember to make the array big enough, smaller arrays its not noticeable ofc.

Answer (score 2):

```
$formatted = sprintf("%.2f", $number);
```

Comment: To use with an array possibly try `vsprintf("%.2f", $numbers_array)`

Answer (score 1):

use the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function before entering values into array :

```
number_format($number, 2)
//will change 7 to 7.00
```